# Using Li-Ion battery while charging

Tags: dc-dc-converter, charging, lithium-ion

I'm trying to design a custom intelligent electronic cigarette battery, but I'm more of a programming guy. I know basic electronics, but I need some help with the details.

I've sketched up an outline of my future ecig, with STM32 as a core, high discharge current 26650 battery, 2" e-ink display and some powerful DC-DC converter like PDT012A0X.

But I'm unsure how to go on about charging that thing. I want it to have embedded charging circuit taking power from the USB port. But I also want to have an ability to use it while it's charging.

There can up pretty high currents running from DC-DC converter to the coils (probably up to 10A), so that's where I find my knowledge lacking.

How would one go about that problem? Should I stop the charging process when the coils are firing up? Or it would be OK for it to continue?

I would really appreciate your help or some links where I can educate myself more.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure I read once in some application note somewhere (trying to find it now and failing) that you shouldn't both charge and discharge a li-ion battery at the same time (i.e., draw current from the battery while it is charging).  You should isolate the battery from the load and drive the load from the supply while charging the battery from that same supply. You'd need a more powerful supply in that case.

Comment: Found it, but it doesn't say "shouldn't", only tells you how you can avoid doing it.  Interesting read anyway, with some good schematics: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01149c.pdf

Comment: Actually, there are some reasons given as to why you shouldn't charge and discharge at the same time - such as infinite charge (charge never terminates), etc.

Comment: I would rather not rely on external power supply. After all, I don't need it to operate continuously on 10 amps while it's charging. Just occasional puff now and then.

Comment: I've turned the start of my answer into something closer to English (and not equations) to hopefully make it easier to absorb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) If using USB as an energy source then maximum current that can be sourced from USB is well below the maximum allowed battery charging current so you will have no real problems doing what you describe. ie if the charger is connected to the battery and load is applied the battery discharge current will greatly exceed the available charging current and there will be net discharge. When the load is removed the charger will 'decide' whether the battery is in CC or CV mode. If in CC mode then the available USB charge current will be applied. If in CV mode the charger will limit voltage to Vmax and charge current will be set by the battery.

---

(2) If energy is from a source where Isource max > I battery_charge_max then ...

By definition you cannot charge & discharge a battery simultaneously - the battery only sees the net current flow. This is not pedantry but physics. What **can** get confused is the charger circuit, if it does not properly account for where the the current flow is going and how much there is.

If you can monitor actual battery current as opposed to charger current (or ideally both) then controlling and monitoring what the battery receives is "just a matter of engineering".

If you are able to monitor battery current AND if you are happy to allow battery voltage to drop to be at a maximum of slightly less than V_cv, during simultaneous use, say down from 4.2V to 4.1V, then you can simply control charg-**ER** current such that Vbat_charge < Icc and Vbattery = Vcharger < V_cv. The battery will then always be in a legal state.

If you can control V_bat_charging and V_charger separately (just two MOSFETs and willingness to drop a little voltage across the charger-to-battery one and dissipate the energy difference, then you can charge battery independently of operating the heater. You could use a buck converter to drop this difference but dissipation will usually be bearable - probably not more than a few Watts usually.

I'm happy to expand on the above as required.

Some might argue that "electronic intelligent-cigarette" is an oxymoron :-).

Added:  For USB sourced charging the load current substantially exceeds the available charging current and the battery will at all times undergo net discharge when the load is being supplied. For other more capable charging energy sources this may not be true.

Comment: Ok, I need some time to absorb that info.

P.S. About intelligent ecig oxymoron thing... If you mean that in a sense that intelligent electronic is oxymoron, it's just people call these devices electronic cigarettes, even when they are firing the coil straight from IMR battery, I just wanted to distinguish. If you're about intelligent-cigarette thing, then yeah, it's not very intelligent, but hey, I feel much better now than I was feeling when smoking the "real" ones.

Answer (score 0):

Charger -> battery -> DC-DC converter -> Load

I don't see a problem with this setup. If your batteries are drained and you're trying to consume a large current directly from your charger, then it might not work as planned, but other than that, you should be fine.

Comment: Wouldn't that setup interfere with the charging process? I mean, the charging IC would probably need to remeasure the state of the battery after each fire? For example if it was in the constant voltage mode, but my last puff drained the battery to the state when it should be charged in the constant current mode?

Comment: @Pawlowski A good li-ion battery charger will re-evaluate at very often intervals to see where on the charging curve it should be. There's no reason a battery charger couldn't be electronically switched to an almost full battery vs an almost empty battery. In each case, the battery charger better be frequently resampling the state of charge of the battery prior to applying more charge.

Comment: @Pawlowski To ensure you don't have an issue of infinite charge time, you could ensure you use a current-based end of charge cycle rather than a timer based constant voltage phase charger.

Comment: A potential issue is: **For example purposes** say that the load takes 10A at about 4V, the charger is able to source 10A and Icc_max for the battery is 4A. Then, if the battery and load and charger are all connected simplistically, if the load is active all will be well. But, if the load is not active, the battery may sink 10A which is in excess of its design maximum. Reducing Icharger_max to I_battery_max may help but removes ability to fully power load.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The battery charger should be designed only for charging the battery (not for supplying the circuit) so the I_max from the charger should never exceed what the battery is allowed to sink anyways. Am I missing something?

Comment: @horta - No, your are probably not missing anything :-). As long as Iload > Icharger_max, which will cerytainly be the case for USB sourced charging, then my "potential issue" does not apply.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. Now I get it now. I've selected Russell's answer as accepted because it is more expanded and would probably be more helpful for future searchers. But again, thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a current limited charger it should be fine. 
it will then draw current from battery when the current goes above what the charger can give.
and will charge battery when current draw are below charger capacity